# Why is request argument not returned in response?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm trying to match a location url to this format `/v1/images/{path1}/fetch?imageUrl={imageUrl}` and I managed to do so with this snippet of code

```
location ~ ^/v1/images/(?<path1>[^/]+)/fetch {
    if ($args ~* "imageUrl=.*") {
      set $path1 $arg_path1;
      set_sha1 $variable $arg_imageUrl;
      set $imageUrl "https://testing.com/test/images/$variable/$path1.$image_ext";
      return 200 $imageUrl;
      add_header Content-Type text/plain;
      proxy_pass $imageUrl;
      access_log /etc/nginx/conf.d/log_file.log traffic;
    }
  }
```

But, I'm supposed to have a value for the path1 variable here returned in the response, but I don't get anything. I'm not sure why it's not being returned here, as it's part of the request too.
Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: You are overwriting the `$path1` variable. This variable is created by the regular expression, then you overwrite it with the value of `$arg_path1` (which does not exist). Remove the `set $path1 $arg_path1;` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your Nginx configuration is missing the part that returns the value of the `path1` variable in the response. You can add the `add_header` directive to include the `path1` variable in the response header.

*Example:*

```
location ~ ^/v1/images/(?<path1>[^/]+)/fetch {
  if ($args ~* "imageUrl=.*") {
    set $path1 $arg_path1;
    set_sha1 $variable $arg_imageUrl;
    set $imageUrl "https://testing.com/test/images/$variable/$path1.$image_ext";
    add_header X-Path1 $path1; # add this line to include path1 in the response header
    return 200 $imageUrl;
    add_header Content-Type text/plain;
    proxy_pass $imageUrl;
    access_log /etc/nginx/conf.d/log_file.log traffic;
  }
}
```